# Libraries for Stylus on Meteor.js

Tags: css, meteor, stylus

Searching on libraries for Stylus I've only found Nib.

I was wondering **HOW TO** install and use **Nib** on **Meteor**. The docs for Nib specify how to use it on pure Node.js; what is the procedure on Meteor?

**Also**: are there any other libraries for Stylus on Meteor? This info has been really hard to find since the meteor docs don't say anything.

Answer (score 4):

The docs don't say this, but nib is automatically installed when you `meteor add stylus`. Note that you will still need to `@import 'nib'` at the top of any `.styl` files where you want the nib extensions.

As for the last part of your question, I'm not aware of other libraries for stylus. If you have something specific in mind, please update the question.

Comment: Read there is the (still in beta) Dookie package: http://labs.voronianski.com/dookie-css/ 

I was wondering if there where any other packages.

Answer (score 1):

check out flexbox based grid system with autoprefixer: http://s-grid.meteor.com

You can also use it with Grunt scaffold: https://github.com/juliancwirko/s-grid-grunt and as a standalone npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/s-grid

There is also some other packages which uses nib, autoprefixer etc.: https://atmospherejs.com/?q=stylus